# Mesh face not rotating at the same rate as rest of the mesh

Tags: mesh, bones, faces

When ever I try to move a bone in pose mode, the face of the barrel of the gun doesn't move as fast as the rest of the mesh, resulting in the pictures below.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Any idea on how to fix this?

[image]

Another, earlier version of the setup:
[image]

This one is better.

Comment: maybe if you could show it in solid mode, it would be easier to understand...

Comment: @m.ardito Is the picture I added what you mean?

Comment: sorry, but I still can't understand which is "the face of the barrel of the gun" that "doesn't move as fast as the rest of the mesh"... if you prefer you can share the file on http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ then edit your question adding the provided link text.

Comment: @m.ardito Added the file.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the file, I feel now I can understand what you meant.

in weight paint mode you can see that (at least) some bone have incomplete weights to that arm: some part are blue while they should have been red.

[image]

this is causing a part of the arm not moving with that bone:

[image]

You just need to correct weights (all red) to make it move better with the bone:

[image]

Comment: That's actually the wrong bone, I'm afraid. It's the one above it.

Comment: Also, uploaded a better version of the file, an earlier one.

Comment: this is why you should better explain what you mean, sorry but even with the new file I can't understand. I can't try everything until you spot that I did the right thing... Maybe hide everything except what is needed, and add exact replication steps